# Linux on RPi debian, hidraw write() to USB device outputs a few junk characters to /dev/hidraw0 which if not cleared jam the device

Tags: c, linux, usb, polling, hid

We have a set of USB devices which we monitor using a RPi. The monitoring code polls the devices using hidraw direct interface about once a second. The protocol uses 64 byte packets to send commands and receive data and all responses are 64 bytes long at most.

The same scheme works fine under Windows using the Windows HID driver. On Linux however we use hidraw and find that the device interface gets jammed after a short time resulting in unsuccessful write{}s to the device.

After a lot of investigation I came across a recommendation to try to follow the communication between a host and an hidraw device using this in a terminal:

```
  sudo cat /dev/hidraw0
```

As it turns out, running this command outputs 4-8 bytes of unreadable characters to the terminal every `write()` and unexpectedly it also clears the jam for `hidraw0`. All subsequent `write()`'s and `read()`'s to that device work flawlessly.

If that device is disconnected and then reconnected the jam condition returns shortly thereafter. I have single stepped the code and verified that the "junk" is output during the execution of the `write()`.

I tried to add `fsync()` calls before and after the `write()` in hope to clear the buffers and avoid this issue but that did not help. The code for the `write()` and subsequent `read()` is standard as follows:

```
#define USB_PACKET 64
#define USB_WRDELAY 10 //ms

FILE* fd; 
int errno, res;
char packet[USB_PACKET];
fd = 0;

/* Open the Device with non-blocking reads. */
fd = open("/dev/hidraw0", O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK);

if (fd < 0) {
    perror("Unable to open device");
    return 0;    // failure
}
memset(packet, 0x0, sizeof(packet));
packet[0] = 0x34;   // command code - request for USB device status bytes
fsync();
res = write(fd, &packet, sizeof(packet));
fsync();
if (res < 0) {
    printf("Error: %d in USB write()\n", errno);
    close(fd);
    return 0;   // failure
} else {
    usleep(1000*USB_WRDELAY );      // delay gives OS and device time to respond
    res = read(fd, &packet, sizeof(packet));
    
    if (res < 0) {
        printf("Error: %d in USB read()\n", errno);
        close(fd);
        return 0; // failure 
    } else {
        // good read, packet holds the response data
        // process the device data
        close(fd); 
        return 1; // OK
    }
 }  
 return 0; // failure
```

This is a sample of the gibberish we read on the terminal running the `cat` command for each executed `write()`:

```
    4n��@/5 �
```

I am not understanding where this junk comes from and how to get rid of it. I tried several things that did not work out such as adding a `read()` with a timeout before the write - hoping it is some data left from a previous incomplete `read()`.

Also tried to write a smaller buffer as I need only send only a 2 byte command as well as adding a delay between the `open()` and `write()`.

Unfortunately using the cat in the terminal interferes with the hot plug/unplug detection of the USB devices so it is not a solution we can use in deployment.

I'll appreciate any words of wisdom on this.